# how to add a loading animation while its busy

Tags: vb.net

i want to add a loading animation while the form is loading..i tried backgroundworker but i can't get it to work..plz help me out..

```
  Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork
    CharTz.Show()
End Sub

  Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.ProgressChanged
    loadingscreen.show()
End Sub

 Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerCompleted
    loadingscreen.close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you doing the rest of the loading on an async, parallel or background thread?

Comment: sorry but im just a noob..what am trying to do is, i want to show the chartz form but i takes about 3-4secs to show..now i want it to show some loading animation to it..till that chartz form pop ups..

Comment: can you explain more on "*how it actually doesn't work*"? any exception (like *invalid cross thread exception*, or other kind of exception), or your `loadingscreen` (whatever it is) doesn't appear? if the latter you need to give more info about what is `loadingscreen`, it's `show()` and `close()` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the UI stuff must be done on the UI thread.  It doesn't make sense to show a form from the background worker.  Showing the form is a UI thing, so that needs to be done on the main UI thread.  I'm quite certain that it's not true that the "takes about 3-4 seconds to *show*".  It may very well take 3-4 seconds to do *something*, but it's not the *showing-the-form* part that's taking that long.  That form must be doing something when it loads which is slowing it down.  *That's* the stuff that ought to be put in a background worker thread.  If all that slow logic is done in a background thread, then the form will show very quickly and it can then display some sort of animation until the background thread is done doing the work.

Comment: hmmmm...tnx for the enlightenment sir.. :D